# The idxmax function is not working in pandas . degrees-that-pay-back.csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('degrees-that-pay-back.csv')
clean_df = df.dropna()
clean_df['Starting Median Salary'].idxmax()
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 clean_df['Starting Median Salary'].idxmax()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in _f(*args, **kwargs)
65                 f_name = f.**name**.replace("nan", "")
66                 raise TypeError(
---> 67                     f"reduction operation '{f_name}' not allowed for this dtype"
68                 )
69             try:

TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Comment: Hi, what did you conclude after searching that error on the search engine? I get some results...

Answer (score 0):

the error message TypeError implies the datatype you are passing to idxmax() is the wrong type.

idxmax() works on numerical values, if you look at the datatypes for the dataframe `df.info()` you will find that the dataype for 'Starting Median Salary' is an object, which is pandas speak for a string (usually).
You will need to convert the datatype to a numerical type e.g. float.

You can do this by removing the '$' sign

`df['Starting Median Salary'].replace(r'[\$]', '', regex=True)`

The remove the commas in the values

`df['Starting Median Salary'].replace(r'[,]', '', regex=True)`

Finally cast the datatype to a float

`df['Starting Median Salary'].astype('float')`

Now idxmax() should work.